# Json Universal Data Representation As A Schema

Tags: json, schema, data-modeling, jsonschema, datamodel

I'm currently working on a universal way of modelling JSON and am looking for existing implementations or research on the idea and am unable to find the correct information, maybe because I don't know what the thing I'm trying to do is called.

The idea is, a JSON object is given and needs to be transformed to a more universal JSON. This universal schema should tell the specifics of the attributes of the JSON object, like data types, if a value in JSON could be null and formatting details.

For example, take the following JSON:

```
{
  "name": "John Doe",
  "age": 40,
  "dateOfBirth": "25-06-1981",
  "luckyNumbers": [1, 3, 7, 10]
}
```

For any general interpreter the date of birth will not be considered as a date but as a string. To make more known about the JSON data it could be represented as something like this:

```
[
  {
    "key": "name",
    "value": "John Doe",
    "type": "string",
    "nullable": false
  },
  {
    "key": "age",
    "value": 40
    "type": "integer",
    "nullable": true
  },
  {
    "key": "dateOfBirth",
    "value": "25-06-1981"
    "type": "date",
    "nullable": false,
    "format": "dd-mm-yyyy"
  },
  {
    "key": "luckyNumbers",
    "value": [1, 3, 7, 10]
    "type": "integer",
    "mode": "array"
    "nullable": false
  },
]
```

Using a model like this it's more explicit what the data means but still abstract enough to be used in a general way.

The reason for this is because i'm trying to develop a way to create database schema's based on input JSON, in which the JSON should work on multiple databases with different naming, typing etc.

Does somebody know if such data representation already exists and what the name of it is?

Comment: You put the `jsonschema` tag on this. Have you looked at [JSON Schema](https://json-schema.org/)?  There are a lot of implementations, and it's in pretty wide use.

Comment: @gregsdennis Yes I have, I'm also not looking for JSON schema but for the use case in which it is used to describe any form of data, explicitly enough to be able to generate database schemas that work on every database, also data warehouses.

Comment: So you looking for "one schema to validate them all"?  I don't think you're going to find something that does that.

Comment: Haha no, I'm looking for a schema to describe objects and their attributes in the most complete way, including the variable name, type, value, nullability, formatting etc.

Comment: I'm missing the gap between what you want and what JSON Schema provides, then.  I'm not sure what you mean by "variable name" ("property name" maybe?), but JSON Schema does type, value, nullability, formatting, etc, and more.

Comment: I know what json schema can do. There are json schemas made for CI tools or for how a package.json should look. What I'm looking for is a very specific JSON schema in which, let's just say, objects with properties can be defined in their most complete way. What I mean with complete is the attributes of attributes. A string attribute has a key(property name, variable name, attribute name), a value, an optional nullability and maybe a regex format. I am looking for a json schema or another tool that might provide such "object+attribute" description. Not only string, but also ints, dates or uuids

Comment: I'm sorry. I still don't follow how what you want isn't covered.  A schema would be fairly complex, true, but any solution would.  Maybe show an example of how what you want _can't_ be done with JSON Schema.

Comment: My question is not if it can or cannot be done with JSON schema, my question is about if it already has been done so that I don't need to invent it from scratch and make the same mistakes others might have already solved. 

Once more the reason:  I need to create a JSON format generator that can take in a regular JSON object that is send over API and convert it to a custom format, with the help of a developer.

The custom format: Must be able to describe the API JSON response on a more granular level per attribute. The first input in the question must become the second input.

Comment: And to add to that. I'm using the API JSON as an example, the generator must be able to do this to ANY JSON document. The reason this is needed is because I need a general format that describes attributes in JSON objects so that I can convert those to database schema's. Why I want it to be complete is because a database schema should also be complete. You wouldn't want a database where everything is either a string or an int, but rather have dates and timestamps.

Comment: I think you mean something like https://github.com/samshal/scripd ? "Parses database structures defined in json based on a custom jsyn file format and generates corresponding sql queries." - It's old and in PHP though. I'm not aware of any standard format, but many database management applications may have their own.

Comment: @Relequestual Thank you for sharing, this is exactly the kind of thing that i'm looking for, I'm also searching alot for any standard format but it seems like most formats are specific to the tool they're made for (logically). We might have to develop our own format if there is no publicly available formatting for this goal. This link relates to jsyn format and is a really good starting point for us, thank you :)

Comment: Why not use the format they provide, expand it, write tests, and re-implement in a language of your choosing? https://xkcd.com/927/

Comment: I voted to close because you're asking for an off-site resource, which is off-topic. If your question was simply "what is this thing called?" then, that would probably be allowable. It's called something like "Database schema SQL in JSON"